# How can I do order by on a table by using a value other the value in the columns?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table:

[image]

I want to order the results based on the sum of issue_morn+issue_noon+issue_night.

Have tried this:

```
<?php
 $date1="";
 $date2="";
 if(!empty($_POST['datepicker1']) && !empty($_POST['datepicker1'])&& !empty($_POST['issue_noon'])&& !empty($_POST['issue_morn'])&& !empty($_POST['issue_night']))
 {
     $date1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['datepicker1']));
     $date2 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['datepicker2']));
     $issue= (int)$_POST['issue_morn']+(int)$_POST['issue_noon']+(int)$_POST['issue_night'];
          
           
     $sth = $conn->prepare('Select * From inventory where date between :date1 and :date2 ORDER BY :issue');
     $sth->execute(array(':date1'=>$date1,':date2'=>$date2, ':issue'=>$issue));
     $data = $sth->fetchAll(); 
 }
?>
```

But not getting any values. I was getting the date wise values before I had included the 'order by' attribute in query.

Comment: in an order by clause you must give the name of a column, or an aggregate function. You appear to be trying to pass an integer. So if the value of $issue is, for example, 12, then your query will be "Select * From inventory where date between 01/01/2015 and 31/12/2015 ORDER BY 12". 12 is not a column name or an aggregate

Comment: So what's the way out?

Comment: Like I said, you need to use a column name or an aggregate function. I'm guessing you want to achieve something like `Select * From inventory where date between 01/01/2015 and 31/12/2015 ORDER BY SUM(issue_morn) + SUM(issue_noon) + SUM(issue_night)`?

Comment: or do you mean `select *, (issue_morn + issue_noon + issue_night) AS SUM_COUNTS 
from inventory where date between 01/01/2015 and 31/12/2015
order by SUM_COUNTS`